# I've implemented horizontal swipe to spin a player 90 degrees, but spinning the camera breaks my swipe logic. How could I solve this problem?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in Unity and I'm making a top down dungeon crawler with on rail movement, like a chess board with custom tile design. Swiping horizontally spins the player fixed 90 degrees clockwise or counterclockwise depending if the swipe was to the right or to the left, and swiping up moves foward to the tile in front of the player, the dungeon is a graph and the tiles are nodes.

The problem is, it's important that the camera spins along with the player, so I placed the camera as a child of the player object and it spinned as I predicted, but then I realized the axis for the touch input changed as if I had spinned my smart phone 90 degrees, the axis are tied to the camera.

I use `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` to get the first and last points of a swipe.

I am using the variation of `x` and `y` from touch and release spots relative to the screen if `Input.GetTouch(0).phase` is `TouchPhase.Ended`:

```
deltaX = releaseX - touchX;
deltaY = releaseY - touchY;
```

`touchX` and `touchY` come from `touchPosition` variable that holds the first touch position relative to the screen, `releaseX` and `touchY` come from the variable that holds the current touch position of `GetTouch(0)` since it changes ever update.

Swipe upIf `deltaY` is over 1, it means there was a good swipe up, but since I don't want very diagonal swipes, `deltaX` needs to be between -1 and 1 tolerance, if not the swipe is ignored.

Swipe to the rightIf `deltaX` is over 1, it means there was a good swipe to the right, since I don't want very diagonal swipes, `deltaY` needs to be between -1 and 1 tolerance, if not the swipe is ignored.

Swipe to the leftIf deltaX is under -1, it means there was a good swipe to the left, since I don't wan't very diagonal swipes, deltaY needs to be between -1 and 1 tolerance, if not the swipe is ignored.

The logic works until the camera is spinned, suppose I swipe to the right, since the camera spinned, its axis also spinned as if I spinned my fone with my hands, the axis is spinned counterclockwise, swiping to the right have the effect of swiping down.

I got rid of the use of `ScreenToWorld` and watched the console to know the values of the points, but the code still doesn't work because every the values of `x` and `y` must be the same for the same spot on the screen, the world's values will change if the camera moves, so moving the camera will mess with swipe logic because it is something that is relative to the smartphone screen, not the world.

Imagine the point p(0,0), I think I need it to always be the center of the screen because I will use it as a reference to calculate the type of a swipe and if it's valid. Using `ScreenToWorld` and the camera was how I learned to do this. Maybe if I have an anchor in the center of the screen I could use `ScreenToWorld` with it, instead of using the camera. I think it is trivial for developers to deal with touch and camera, so there must be a conventional way of doing it.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: why not use `Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition)`?  then check if it's > 0.1 or < -0.1 and so on?

Comment: `touchPosition` is fine too

Comment: It took me a while to understand that getting the point relative to the camera axis would work, I used Camera.ScreenToViewporPoint instead of Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint and tested the values, the logic works now using 0.05, thank you

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer below. Please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the position of touch relative to the camera. Use `ScreenToViewportPoint` instead of `ScreenToWorldPoint`. You'll probably need to use a smaller threshold, because it's expressed in terms of viewport coverage rather than world units.